# The name of the end part of a film that contains contacts information

Tags: word-choice, word-usage, synonyms, names

What is usually called the part of a film that comes at the end which contains contacts information ?

Comment: "Contact information" usually means phone numbers, email addresses, and/or physical addresses - is that what you're asking about? Or do you just mean the big list of everybody who worked on the film?

Comment: It’s called the credits. I doubt it has much actual contact information.

Answer (score 1):

*[Closing credits](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closing_credits)*.

These are a subset of *[motion picture credits](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Motion_picture_credits)*, typically shortened to *credits*.

> Closing credits or end credits are a list of the cast and crew of a particular motion picture

> [C]losing credits will typically acknowledge all staff members that were involved in the production

Both references from the Wikipedia links above.

Specific contact information is typically included.

Comment: Thank you for that, but just wondering i’ve heard people in the UK using ‘background’e.g ‘background contacts’ but not sure if they refer to this particular part ?

Comment: I haven't heard that term, and I can't find anything on a quick google search.